# Differential operator linear on $S^1$.

Tags: operator-theory, manifolds, vector-bundles

I have been studying differential operators on varieties on Liviu Nicolaescu's book "Lectures on the Geometry of Manifolds" and I have managed to understand how to go from differential operators on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to operators on smooth manifolds but, when wanting to apply to a simple exercise, for example, the derivative operator on the variety $S^1$. I don't know how to apply the theory to this operator.

I know that, $S^1$ is a manifold. At $(1,0)\in S^1$ thre exists $T_{(1,0)}(S^1)$, the tangent space at $(1,0)$. Consider the differential operator $d/dx:C^{\infty}(E)\to C^{\infty}(E)$ and define $C^{\infty}(E):=\left\{s:S^1\to E:s \text{ smooth section}\right\}$ and let $\pi:E\to S^1$ be vector bundle.

How can I make sense of this operator? Or can one not make sense of it?

Additionally, the bundle I take is $E=\left\{v\in \mathbb{R}^2: v\perp (1,0)\right\}$

I can't quite understand the operators on varieties when applying it to a simple exercise.

Comment: It looks like the $E$ you define is the tangent space of the circle at $(1,0)$. Maybe you mean that you would like $E$ to be the tangent bundle - where every point $p\in S^1$ is associated to its tangent space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the exponential form $\rho e^{i\theta}$ to express elements in $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}=\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$.
Now you can think $\mathbb S^1$ as a subset of $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$ defined by $\rho=1$.
Take the map $\pi:\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb S^1$ s.t. $\pi(\rho e^{i\theta})=e^{i\theta}$. Now we have a structure of vector bundle.
As trivialization take the bijection
$$\Phi:\pi^{-1}(\mathbb S^1)\to \mathbb S^1\times \mathbb R$$
$$\rho e^{i\theta}\mapsto (e^{i\theta},\log(\rho)).$$
So if $E:=\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$, the map $\dfrac{d}{dx}:\mathcal C^{\infty}(E)\to \mathcal C^{\infty}(E)$ is a linear function that satisfies Leibniz's rule.

Comment: Regarding trivialization I understand it, but I still don't know how this operator works. I just saw a definition, and that operator has the representation, 
$d/dx[s](x)=\Phi^{-1}(d/dx(\left.\Phi\circ s)\right|_{x})$
where $x\in U, U\subset S^1$ (coordinate neighborhood).
This is correct?

Comment: I've seen you have defined the tangent space at $\mathbb S^1$ in $(1,0)$. Are you sure you are not confusing the differential map with the derivation? Because if we take a smooth section, it is a function $\sigma:\mathbb S^1\to \mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$ and we can define the (linear) differential in $(1,0)$  of $\sigma$ as $$\sigma_{*(1,0)}:T_{(1,0)}\mathbb S^1\to T_{\sigma(1,0)}\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}.$$

Comment: Now you  can define a basis (using a local chart $\varphi$) of $T_{(1,0)}\mathbb S^1$ as $$\dfrac{d}{dx}\vert_p:=(\varphi_{*\varphi(p)})^{-1}(\dfrac{d}{dr}\Big\vert_{\varphi(p)}).$$